# Php regex to remove duplicated words

Tags: php, regex

I have string:

```
$s = 'Артгалерея Живопись Африка и от the Albert$Lizah, L-77, Christ UF1.1 (Christ).';
```

I wish to receive in a array the next string:

```
$s = 'Артгалерея Живопись Африка Albert Lizah Christ';
```

I used regex:

```
   preg_match_all('#\pL{4,}+#iu', $s, $m);
   $m = preg_replace("/\b(\w+)\s+\\1\b/i", "$1", implode(' ',$m[0]));
   $m = explode(' ', $m);
   echo '<pre>'.print_r($m, 1).'</pre>';
```

And received:

```
$s = 'Артгалерея Живопись Африка Albert Lizah Christ Christ';
```

But I can not receive a string without duplicating words.

**Question**: How to change regular expression php - '#\pL{4,}+#iu', to exclude inclusion in a string of duplicating words?

Thank you very much!

Comment: preg_match_all('#\b(\pL{4,}+)\b(?!.*\b\1\b)#iu', $s, $m) - The fine decision, one only me confuses that it is impossible to receive one array instead of two. Can eat nevertheless the decision of a similar problem with one array. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead assertion with a backreference:

```
    \b(\pL{4,}+)\b(?!.*\b\1\b)
```

Comment: I do preg_match_all('#(?:\b(\pL{4,}+)\b(?!.*\b\1\b))+#iu', $s, $m) and I have received two array. Why? Thank.

Comment: You get two arrays because [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) returns an array of arrays: one array for each "match index." (Read the section on ``PREG_PATTERN_ORDER``, the default mode.) So, in other words, the first array is the set of all full-pattern matches (``$0``s); the second array is the set of all 1st-capture-group matches (``$1``s). In your original example, you didn't have any capture groups ``()`` so you only saw one array: the full-pattern matches. In this example, we require a capture group to provide the backreference ``\1``.

Comment: It is I get on output:Array( [0] => Array ([0] => Артгалерея  [1] => Живопись [2] => Африка[3] => Albert [4] => Lizah[5] => Christ ) [1] => Array([0] => Артгалерея[1] => Живопись[2] => Африка[3] => Albert[4] => Lizah [5] => Christ)). And how to make, that I have received one a array, instead of two? Where in my code above an error?

Comment: I just realized that ``\0`` backreferences the full match. Here, try this: ``preg_match_all('#\b(?:\pL{4,}+)\b(?!.*\b\0\b)#iu', $s, $m)``.

Comment: Ah, it was silly of me to think ``\0`` would backreference the full match: how can the engine backreference what it hasn't finished matching?  You will have to live with two arrays, and selecting one of them, like so: ``preg_match_all('#\b(\pL{4,}+)\b(?!.*\b\1\b)#iu', $s, $m)[0]``.

Comment: preg_match_all('#\b(\pL{4,}+)\b(?!.*\b\1\b)#iu', $s, $m)[0] - I received two array's anew. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I meant: ``preg_match_all('#\b(\pL{4,}+)\b(?!.*\b\1\b)#iu', $s, $m)`` and then use ``$m[0]`` as your array.  It is impossible to return a single array.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/array_unique) on preg_match_all's result:

```
...
$words = array_unique($m[0]);
...
```

Comment: Thank you very mach. How add my regular expression (#\pL{4,}+#iu) what to remove duplicated words in place of array_unique? I wish to receive array after one regular expression! It is possible? Thanks