# Regex match with identical words

Tags: php, regex

*Assuming **YES**, **OR** and **YES** are random words (provided that the 2 **YES** are the same) and are only here for representation :*

I am trying to use regex to match **YES**, **OR** and **YES** in any place, with the condition that ***the string must only match if it has 2 YES***.

So if i try to use the following test strings :

```
yes or yes
no or yes
yes or no
maybe yes or yes
maybe yes or no
yes maybe or yes
maybe yes maybe yes maybe or
```

It should only match the following :

```
yes or yes
maybe yes or yes
yes maybe or yes
maybe yes maybe yes maybe or
```

Here's my regex query which I am working on :

```
^(?=.*(?=\w.*yes)(?=\w.*or)(?=\w.*yes)).*
```

Unfortunately, my query still matches `no or yes`.
Here's my regex link : [Click Here](https://regex101.com/r/rpi1kw/1)

Comment: i would just use two regex, but - i know - that was not the question

Comment: @snitch182 i prefer a single regex, but would consider any suggestion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11348371/php-regex-to-remove-duplicated-words

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823016/regular-expression-for-consecutive-duplicate-words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not  so?

```
^(?=.*\byes\b.+\byes\b)(?=.*\bor\b).+
```

The first Positive Lookahead finds two `yes`, and the second one matches `or`

[**demo on regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/rpi1kw/3)

Answer (score 0):

A **non-regex** way using `substr_count()`

```
<?php
$string = 'yes or yes
no or yes
yes or no
maybe yes or yes
maybe yes or no
yes maybe or yes
maybe yes maybe yes maybe or';
$array =   explode("\n", $string);
$expected = [];
//print_r($array);
foreach($array as $line){
    $words = substr_count($line,'yes');
    if($words==2 && strpos($line, 'or') !== false ){
     $expected[]= $line;   
    }
}

echo implode("\n",$expected);
```

**Output:**

```
yes or yes
maybe yes or yes
yes maybe or yes
maybe yes maybe yes maybe or
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/uL7fJ